# PowerBI: USERELATIONSHIP() based on column value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a relationship between **'CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio'[PeriodenRegiocode]** and **'PeriodenProvinciecode'[PeriodenProvinciecode]** or **'PeriodenCOROPcode'[PeriodenCOROPcode]**, depending on the value in **'CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio'**. IF the value in **'CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio'[PeriodenRegiocode]** starts with 'PV', the active relationship should be with **[PeriodenProvinciecode]**, else it should be with **[PeriodenCOROPcode]**.

It's quite a difficult model because the tables are connected with a hiearchy (Country-Province-Region-Municipality), which is also dependent on time (Every year a couple municipalities merge)

[Model view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm1E5.png)

[CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoUL.png)

[PeriodenProvinciecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnbVw.png)

[PeriodenCOROPcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4xZO.png)

PeriodenProvinciecode and PeriodenCOROPcode will be connect to the main hierarchy table:
[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5ZhY.png)

Does anyone have a solution? I've been struggling for a couple of hours already

The closest I've come was with the following code. The values for COROP (**PeriodenCOROPcode[PeriodenCOROPcode]**) are returned correctly. The values for (**PeriodenProvinciecode[PeriodenProvinciecode]**) however, seem to be the summed amount of COROP values.

```
IF(
    LEFT(SELECTEDVALUE('CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio'[Regiocode]),2)="PV", 
    CALCULATE(SUM(CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio[Gemiddeld besteedbaar inkomenParticuliere huishoudens excl. Studenten]),USERELATIONSHIP(CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio[PeriodenRegiocode],PeriodenProvinciecode[PeriodenProvinciecode])),
    CALCULATE(SUM(CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio[Gemiddeld besteedbaar inkomenParticuliere huishoudens excl. Studenten]),USERELATIONSHIP(CBS_InkomenVermogenRegio[PeriodenRegiocode],PeriodenCOROPcode[PeriodenCOROPcode])))
```